# How to wait with returning until a certain event?

Tags: ios, swift, cloud

I have a function that saves Data to iCloud

```
func save(data: Data) -> Bool {
    cloudRecord["example"] = data as CKRecordValue
    var success = false
    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(self.cloudRecord) { (record, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print(1)
            success = true
        }
    }

    print(2)
    return success
}
```

The problem is, that the `print(2)` is executed before the `print(1)` so the function always returns success which is false, because it is returned before having the chance of changing.

How do I get this code to return the value after the success has been set?

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning bool from the method add an argument with a closure like this. When you receive a response from `privateCloudDatabase.save` call the closure with bool value.

```
func save(data: Data, completion:(Bool)->Void) {
    cloudRecord["notes"] = data as CKRecordValue
    var success = false
    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(self.cloudRecord) { (record, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            print(1)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Change your function calling as follows

```
save(data: data) { result in
    print("result is \(result)")
}
```